# Изменение валюты у одного тура при это не изменяя остальные

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть в теории такая задача - на сайте на Вордпрессе есть слайдер туров с ценниками В USD, у всех туров одинаковая структура(дивы с классами), добавить дополнительные классы для css нет возможности, но для одного тура надо вывести цену средствами php в EURO, как в теории это сделать? Что можно почитать,сделать?

Comment: Написать условие для этого "одного тура" и конвертировать вывод цены из USD в EURO

Comment: А как, за что цепляться? просто по сути одинаковые item`ы просто картинка разная,и цена

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создай доп. поле для валюты и проверяй его